# Failed to get type for: content://com.android.calendar (Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar) - Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-calendar

I am trying to make an application which will add a new event in our native android calendar.I am getting an error `content://com.android.calendar` and not able to figure it out what is wrong happening.

`I am using KitKat verson of android.`

can anyone help me out here please.

**Here is my code :**

**Postcalendar code :**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.net.Uri;

public class postcalendar {

    public postcalendar()
    {

    }

    public long pushAppointmentsToCalender(Activity curActivity, String title,
            String addInfo, String place, int status, long startDate) {
        /***************** Event: note(without alert) *******************/

        String eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
        ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
        eventValues.put("calendar_id", 1); // id, We need to choose from
        // our mobile for primary
        // its 1
        eventValues.put("title", title);
        eventValues.put("description", addInfo);
        eventValues.put("eventLocation", place);
        eventValues.put("eventTimezone", "UTC/GMT +2:00");

        long endDate = startDate + 1000 * 60 * 60; // For next 1hr

        eventValues.put("dtstart", startDate);
        eventValues.put("dtend", endDate);
        eventValues.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
        eventValues.put("eventStatus", status);

        Uri eventUri = curActivity.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues);
        long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
        return eventID;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity :**

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import com.post.calendar.CalendarTest;
import com.post.calendar.postcalendar;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void alarmtest(View view) {
        postcalendar cal = new postcalendar();
        Activity myactivity = this;
        cal.pushAppointmentsToCalender(myactivity, "POST Test","Test calendar", "Hwc", 1, 20140930);

       }
```

**LogCat:**

```
10-03 12:37:39.848: I/CalendarProvider2(8239): Sending notification intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED dat=content://com.android.calendar }
10-03 12:37:39.848: W/ContentResolver(8239): Failed to get type for: content://com.android.calendar (Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar)
10-03 12:37:39.858: D/AlertReceiver(8286): onReceive: a=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED dat=content://com.android.calendar flg=0x10 cmp=com.android.calendar/.alerts.AlertReceiver }
10-03 12:37:39.878: D/AlertService(8286): 0 Action = android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED
10-03 12:37:39.878: D/AlertReceiver(8311): onReceive: a=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED dat=content://com.android.calendar flg=0x10 cmp=com.google.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.alerts.AlertReceiver }
10-03 12:37:39.898: D/AlertService(8311): 0 Action = android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED
```

Answer (score 0):

I got essentially the same messages via logcat:

```
I/CalendarProvider2(24598): Sending notification intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED dat=content://com.android.calendar }
W/ContentResolver(24598): Failed to get type for: content://com.android.calendar (Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar)
W/ContentResolver(24598): Failed to get type for: content://com.android.calendar/1431376560000 (Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar/1431376560000)
```

while calendar notifications did not work.
It was simply because I had disabled the Calendar app.
So un-freezing com.android.calendar solved the issue for me.